# Mysql get lowest price from 3 tables. Improve efficiency

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization, min

I have 3 tables as follows,

```
1. Link_products_price
DESC: unique_id|product_id|sub_category_id.
2. local_price
DESC: unique_id|price.
3. online_price
DESC: unique_id|price.
```

I want to select the lowest price for a given product_id|sub_category_id.

I came up with the following,

Approach 1:

```
SELECT MIN(price) 
FROM local_price 
WHERE unique_id IN (SELECT unique_id 
                    FROM link_products_price 
                    WHERE product_id=1 
                    AND sub_category_id=1) 

UNION 

SELECT MIN(price) 
FROM online_price 
WHERE unique_id IN (SELECT unique_id 
                    FROM link_products_price 
                    WHERE product_id=1 
                    AND sub_category_id=1) 
LIMIT 1;
```

Approach 2 :

Create a VIEW with an INNER JOIN on these 3 tables and query MIN(price) from the view when it is required from the application.

But then, view would execute the query only during run time.

Please tell me whether the query in approach 1 is OK or if it can be further optimized and advice on the `VIEW` approach too.

Answer (score 3):

Your first approach always selects the minimum local price: you'd need to add an `ORDER BY` clause to ensure the minimum of the two is selected by the `LIMIT`.  However, it would be simpler to [join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) the queries and use MySQL's [`LEAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) function in combination with `MIN()` aggregation:

```
SELECT LEAST(MIN(local_price.price), MIN(online_price.price))
FROM   link_products_price
  LEFT JOIN  local_price USING (unique_id)
  LEFT JOIN online_price USING (unique_id)
WHERE link_products_price.product_id = 1
  AND link_products_price.sub_category_id = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can I politely request you to explain to me about the good things in this query?. In a way I understand LEFT JOIN's necessity in this scenario. Instead of blindly copying and pasting the query I want to know, why? because next time I will write it myself. Thanks again.

Comment: @beck03076: Outer joins are only necessary (versus inner ones) in case there are no matching records in the price tables; although, that said, in such a situation `LEAST()` will result in a `NULL` value so outer joins actually don't add much here at all and you could simply dispose of the `LEFT` keywords.  PS, the word "join" in my answer is a link to a good tutorial on joins.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of efficiency (not readability) I'd probably go with something similar to your first example, except that your example contains an error - you assume the UNION sorts the results?

Try this corrected version instead:

```
SELECT LEAST(

    (SELECT MIN(price) 
     FROM local_price 
     WHERE unique_id IN (SELECT unique_id 
                         FROM link_products_price 
                         WHERE product_id=1 
                         AND sub_category_id=1))
    ,
    (SELECT MIN(price) 
     FROM online_price 
     WHERE unique_id IN (SELECT unique_id 
                         FROM link_products_price 
                         WHERE product_id=1 
                         AND sub_category_id=1))
)
```

But unless you have hundreds of millions of rows you'll probably find that the query goes so fast even if you use a less efficient method that it doesn't matter which is fastest.

The most important thing to get efficiency is to make sure that you have the appropriate **indexes**.

I'd suggest adding the following indexes:

- link_products_price (product_id, sub_category_id)
- local_price (unique_id , price)
- online_price (unique_id , price)

Comment: I heard joins are faster than sub-queries. Can I benchmark your answer and eggyal's answer?. What is the best way to benchmark mysql queries? Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: @beck03076: "I heard joins are faster than sub-queries." Sometimes, but that doesn't mean it's always true. "Can I benchmark your answer and eggyal's answer?" I don't know! I know that *I* can, but I don't know if *you* can. Try it and let us know! "What is the best way to benchmark mysql queries?" Try running both on your data. Chances are that both will be so fast that it doesn't matter. Or both will be slow because you didn't add indexes. The *most important thing* for improving performance is adding appropriate **indexes**. Just in case you missed it: **INDEXES!!!**

Comment: A join is sometimes faster than subqueries. But this has only subqueries that return 1 row each. And your other way has 2 `LEFT` joins. I would bet that this wat would be most performant - even better if the two `IN` were rewritten with `INNER JOIN`.